# SELECT Colunm_Name Column_Name from Table_Name (no comma)

Tags: sql, syntax

so i was wondering why:

```
SELECT Colunm_Name Column_Name from Table_Name
```

**WITHOUT** a comma between column names does not return a syntax error, instead it return records with the first column only. At first i thought the comma was optional, but then i tried:

```
SELECT Colunm_Name Column_Name Column_Name from Table_Name
```

and this returns a syntax error near the third column. Any idea why? is there a reason why you could put two column names without a comma even though it omits the second column? Thnx!

Comment: Feel free to try it here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing a word next to a column is treated as the alias for the selected column. The result for the query will display that alias as the column name. Here, `AS` keyword is ommitted. e.g.

```
SELECT Column_Name1 AS Column_Name2 FROM EMPLOYEE
```

is same as

```
SELECT Column_Name1 Column_Name2 FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Both, the queries will return the data with one column and the column header will be **Column_Name2**

Whereas, the third word will be treated as syntax error:

```
SELECT Column_Name1 Column_Name2 Column_Name3 FROM EMPLOYEE
```

will return error as it will be expecting a **comma** or `FROM` keyword just after `Column_Name2` word.

You can study more about it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alias-syntax.htm) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: @NahuelPeruzzo if you are satisfied with my answer, could you please select it as correct answer? Thanks!